# C How do i cast a scalar type to a non scalar and backwards?

Tags: c

i declared myself a bitfield (u8 means unsinged integer 8)

```
typedef struct build_field{

    u8 build : 5;
    u8 ability : 1;
    u8 hability : 1;
    u8 shinyness : 1;

} build_field;
```

Now i want to cast an incoming u8 value returned by a function so i can use it as a bitfield.

```
build_field f = (build_field) func_that_returns_u8();
```

Also i would like to cast it back to an u8 value.

```
u8 x = (u8) field;
```

But my C compiler wont let me do any of that operations. Any idea how to fix the problem?

Comment: `u8 val = 0xb5; build = val & 0x1f; ability = (val & 0x20) >> 5; hability = (val & 0x40) >> 6; shinyness = (val & 0x80) >> 7;` or whatever order you want the bits in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a union:

```
union myunion
{
    u8 value;
    build_field field;
};

union myunion m;
m.value = func_that_returns_u8();
u8 a = m.ability;
```

Make sure there is no padding in between the members in the struct `build_field` otherwise this will not work.

A more sensible option is to extract the bits from the integer. Let's say the bits in the value are in the same order as the members in the struct. To get the values of `hability` and `ability` you do:

```
u8 value = func_that_returns_u8();
build_field f = { 0 };
f.hability = ( ( unsigned int )value >> 6U ) & 1U;
f.ability = ( ( unsigned int )value >> 5U ) & 1U;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return whole structs in C. Combined with `static`, this can be inlined, too (starts with -O1 in gcc)

```
static build_field compose_field(unsigned char uc)
{
union {
        unsigned char uc;
        build_field bf;
        } uni = {uc};
return uni.bf;
}
```

---

Usage

```
int main(void)
{
build_field val;

val = compose_field(0xa5 ); // "constructor"
printf(" {%u %u %u %u}\n"
        , (unsigned int)  val.build
        , (unsigned int)  val.ability
        , (unsigned int)  val.hability
        , (unsigned int)  val.shinyness
        );
return 0;
}
```

---

GCC output with -O2:

```
main:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    andl    $-16, %esp
    subl    $32, %esp
    movl    $1, 20(%esp)
    movl    $0, 16(%esp)
    movl    $1, 12(%esp)
    movl    $5, 8(%esp)
    movl    $.LC0, 4(%esp)
    movl    $1, (%esp)
    call    __printf_chk
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    leave
    ret
```

---

With non-constant argument: (`uc = 0xa5 * random();` ) :

```
main:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    andl    $-16, %esp
    subl    $32, %esp
    call    random
    movl    $-91, %ecx
    xorl    %edx, %edx
    movl    $.LC0, 4(%esp)
    movl    $1, (%esp)
    imull   %ecx, %eax
    movb    %al, %dl
    movl    %edx, %eax
    shrl    $7, %eax
    movl    %eax, 20(%esp)
    movl    %edx, %eax
    shrl    $6, %eax
    andl    $1, %eax
    movl    %eax, 16(%esp)
    movl    %edx, %eax
    andl    $31, %edx
    shrl    $5, %eax
    andl    $1, %eax
    movl    %eax, 12(%esp)
    movl    %edx, 8(%esp)
    call    __printf_chk
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    leave
    ret
```